# How to overlead operator with 2 object in

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I learn to exam, and I do class with operator overleading. I know how to overlead operator, but I have problem with operator overleading += and -=: I want to that passengers with second bus change to first bus  as many people as you can.

```
class bus
{
private:
    const int howSeat;
    int howTake;
public:
    bus(int s=51, int z=0);
    int Free();
     Passenger();
    bus &operator+=(bus k);
    bus & operator-=(bus k);

};

bus &bus::operator+=(bus k)
{
    howTaken+=k.howTaken;
    return *this;
}


int bus::Passanger()
{
    return howTaken;
}

int bus::free()
{
    return HowSeat-HowTaken;
}

bus::bus(int s, int z):howSeat(s)
{
    howTaken=z;
    if(howTaken<0 ||  howTaken>howSeat)
    {
       howTaken=0;
    }
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what problem you have with the shown code. Note that there is a typo in it: `int howTake;` -> `int howTaken;` and that your `main` doesn't actually do anything besides printing `Hello World!`.

Comment: You have *several* typos in your code. Listen to the compiler, it will tell you exactly what's wrong. If it says it can't find a symbol that you know should exist, check the spelling. And remember that names are case-sensitive: `HowTaken` is different from `howTaken`.

Comment: I want that passenger get out with second bus and get in to first bus but i don't know to write in c++, so if someone write code and explain how that work i will gratefull

Comment: Please take some time to read about (or refresh) [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't need to return something in the overloaded functions, it perfectly works with void. To make possible what you want, you need to use '&'( for example: funstion( type &variable)), it means that you take the address of the variable, so the changes will also be made in the original one. You can see it in this example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class bus
{
private:
    const int howSeat;
    int howTaken;
public:
    bus(int s=51, int z=0);
    int Passanger();
    void operator+=(bus &k);
};

void bus::operator+=(bus &k) // now all changes made in k, will also be made in bus2
{
    if ((k.howTaken + howTaken) > howSeat)
    {
        k.howTaken = k.howTaken + howTaken - howSeat;
        howTaken = howSeat;
    }
    else
    {
        howTaken += k.howTaken;
        k.howTaken = 0;
    }
}


int bus::Passanger()
{
    return howTaken;
}

bus::bus(int s, int z):howSeat(s)
{
    howTaken = z;

    if( howTaken < 0 || howTaken > howSeat)
    {
       howTaken=0;
    }
}
int main()
{
    bus bus1(20, 4);
    bus bus2(20, 9);

    cout << bus1.Passanger() << " " << bus2.Passanger() << endl;

    bus1 += bus2;

    cout << bus1.Passanger() << " " << bus2.Passanger();
    return 0;
}
```